# check if a movieclip exists on a specific location relative to event.currentTarget

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

**How can I check if the stage contains a movieclip on a specific x and y location on the stage?**

I'm building a colour-guessing game. The purpose is to walk a path through a generated field of hexagons, each assigned a random colour (yellow, red, blue or green), based on what soundfile you hear. So if you hear "yellow", you have to click a yellow tile etc.

But because I want it to be a path, and the colours of the tiles are randomly generated, I have to check which colours border the currently active tile. 
I literally have no idea how to do this.

I thought this might work but it doesnt:

```
if ((this.tile.y == (event.currentTarget.y - 64)) != null) { 
    //add the colour of this tile to array
}
```

I also see some problems in how to check if the next tile clicked borders on the previously active tile :( It's getting slightly overcomplicated for me. I would really appreciate your views on this.

So my current question is:
**how do I check if a tile exists on stage that borders my active tile?**

Edit again: the game should be a simpler version of this one: http://elt.oup.com/student/i-spy/games/colour

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about the situation, but I think you should add an eventListener on these tiles so that if you click on them, the color is checked with the current color that has to be clicked. Are you working actionscript 3 based? This shouldn't be to hard but it's hard to explain.

Comment: Thank you for your time and input, but I'm afraid you're not referring to my question at all.

Comment: If you don't like this approach you can always try a hittestpoint? Than as point you provide the mouse coordinates: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#hitTestPoint%28%29

Comment: I don't need to know how to check if a tile is clicked, I have that covered with an eventListener. I need to know how I can determine if tiles are surrounding my active tile, and if so, what colour they have. That way I can determine the next possible options of the path. (or am i misunderstanding the possiblities of hittestpoint?)

Answer (score 0):

When you randomly generate your tiles, store them.  You may find that a linked list or doubly linked list works well for this--if you have a reference to the tile, you automatically have a reference to the bordering tile(s) http://www.developria.com/2009/12/iterative-data-storage-in-as3.html

Comment: I see what you mean. It's still pretty difficult for me to grasp (I'm having trouble thinking in arrays and lists) but I think this could get me somewhere.

Comment: alas, too difficult for me at this point. I don't suppose there's an easier way?

Comment: Try picking an easier problem until you feel confident enough to tackle this one.